# Directly bind data to a setter value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, setter

How could I bind a brush from my ViewModel to a setter value?

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectionBrush, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding SelectionBrush, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>

class Leerformular
{
    public Leerformular()
    {
        SelectionBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter()).ConvertFromString(settings.SelectionBrush);
    }

    public SolidColorBrush SelectionBrush
    {
        get { return selectionBrush; }
        set
        {
            if (selectionBrush != value && value != null)
            {
                selectionBrush = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectionBrush");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the program nothing is happening when I select the cells.

Comment: Is `Leerformular` the class behind each item of `DataGrid`?

Comment: how you use the class `Leerformular`? is that a view-model? how exactly you use it?

Comment: Verify that your style is working by just setting an actual color in your style. Report back to us if that works or does not. Also how are you specifying the grids datacontext? Is it simply inheriting the page's datacontext which is bound to the view model?

Comment: The class `Leerformular` is the view-model and the style is working well.